# How can I save this file?

Tags: c#, file, save, notepad, savefiledialog

So i am creating a C# notepad, i am almost done, but theres is one last problem:
I cant save the file. When I open a file, modify it, and try to save it, it gives me an error saying the file is already in use by a process. I believe that this process is started by my open file method, but im not sure. I do have a method to save that open a save file dialog, but I want one that needs no dialog, just a quick  *cntrl n* to save it, you may understand what i mean.

My open file method

```
 private void openItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                string srtfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string filetext = File.ReadAllText(srtfilename);
                GetRichTextBox().Text = filetext;

                tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                GlobalPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }

            openFileDialog1.Dispose();
        }
```

My save file method WITH dialog, this one works, but  if i select the file that I am already using, it crashes.

```
 private void saveAsItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (Stream s = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            { sw.Write(GetRichTextBox().Text); }

            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);

            saveFileDialog1.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

My *quick* save file method, the one im having problem with. This is what i have tried so far.

```
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string texto, nome, local;
        nome = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text;
        texto = GetRichTextBox().Text;
        tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
        NewText();
        GetRichTextBox().Text = texto;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = nome;

        local = nome + ".txt";

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(GlobalPath, true))
        { sw.Write(texto); }

     // tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = Path.GetFileName(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you debug your app and look at the Exception being thrown?

Comment: @Fang Easier to post a question here I'd guess...

Comment: @Fang The exception being thrown here doesn't tell you what the owning process is, only that something else owns the file and to go find it yourself.  Granted, the solution is still discoverable if you include the context of opening a file with a stream, but the exception alone isn't enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method for opening and reading a file is overly complicated, and I think it's the source of your problem. You're leaving a `Stream` object un-disposed. Anything that implements `IDisposable` should be wrapped in a `using` statement or explicitly disposed.

Here's a better implementation of your open file method:

```
private void openItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try {
                string srtfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string filetext = File.ReadAllText(srtfilename);
                GetRichTextBox().Text = filetext;

                tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

                GlobalPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                // you may wish to log the entire exception including stack trace here
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need the stream just to check if a file exists. And now you aren't leaving any undisposed resources that would hold the file open.

You could also use `if (File.Exists(strfilename))` to check if the file exists, or just don't do the check, since the FileOpenDialog will actually warn the user by default (I think), if the file doesn't exist.

You should stick with `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText`: there's no need to be messing with `Stream` objects directly for a simple text editor, and it's cleaner and leaves you with simpler code.

Comment: The only thing I would add to this answer is that `FileNotFoundException` is far from the only exception that can throw from `File.ReadAllText()` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an exhaustive list).  There should either be multiple catch blocks for each exception type that each display a unique message, or one block that catches a generic `Exception` and displays whatever `ex.Message` happens to contain.